# NumberFormat - Currency

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with my code.
I send a number but the format does not working.

My code is the next.

```
class SetValueClass extends HelperClass {
  SetValueClass() : super();

  String transformValue({
    required double number,
    bool? pasa,
  }) {
    number = 27126677097.04;
    SuffixOptions suffixOptions = getSuffixObject(number);

    if (pasa != null && pasa) {
      print(number);
      print(suffixOptions.name);
      print(suffixOptions.format);
      print(suffixOptions.number);
      print(suffixOptions.suffix);
    }

    final numberFormat = NumberFormat.currency(
      locale: 'es_CO',
      // customPattern: '',
      symbol: suffixOptions.suffix,
    );

    numberFormat.maximumFractionDigits = suffixOptions.format['maximumFractionDigits']!;
    numberFormat.minimumFractionDigits = suffixOptions.format['minimumFractionDigits']!;

    return numberFormat.format(number);
  }
}
```

The final result i want, is parse 27126677097.04 to 27,127 MM, but y received this...
27.126.677.097,04 MM

The symbol is working successfully, but, ¿how can i compact this number and return 27,127 MM?

Note: The locale es_CO is the code of Colombia.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I realized that the es_CO did not work the way I needed it to, so I decided to go with the following solution.

Create a function.

```
 String _defineValue({required number}) {
    /**
     * Valor en el rango de cuatrillones.
     * (C)
     */
    if (number > 1e+24) {
      return "${(number / 1e+24).toStringAsFixed(2)} C";
    }

    /**
     * Valor en el rango de miles de trillones.
     * (MT)
     */
    if (number > 1e+21) {
      return "${(number / 1e+21).toStringAsFixed(3)} MT";
    }

    /**
     * Valor en el rango de trillones.
     * (T)
     */
    if (number > 1e+18) {
      return "${(number / 1e+18).toStringAsFixed(2)} T";
    }

    /**
     * Valor en el rango de miles de billones.
     * (MB)
     */
    if (number > 1e+15) {
      return "${(number / 1e+15).toStringAsFixed(3)} MB";
    }

    /**
     * Valor en el rango de billones.
     * (MB)
     */
    if (number > 1e+12) {
      return "${(number / 1e+12).toStringAsFixed(2)} B";
    }

    /**
     * Valor en el rango de miles de millones.
     * (MM)
     */
    if (number > 1e+9) {
      return "${(number / 1e+9).toStringAsFixed(3)} MM";
    }

    /**
     * Valor en el rango de millones.
     * (M)
     */
    if (number > 1e+6) {
      return "${(number / 1e+6).toStringAsFixed(2)} M";
    }

    /**
     * Valor en el rango de inferior
    */
    return "${(number / 1).toStringAsFixed(0)}";
  }
```

This function gets a number and return a String with the logic required in my case.